# How to web-scrape from fragment (#) menu

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm new to webscraping, I can do the basics using rvest, but the info I want is in a #fragment;

https://www.neurosynth.org/analyses/terms/dorsomedial%20prefrontal/#studies

If I run

```
website <- https://www.neurosynth.org/analyses/terms/dorsomedial%20prefrontal/#studies
website %>% html_elements("#analysis-studies-table a")
```

having used the selector gadget to find the CSS code from the "Studies" sub-menu, it returns a null result, I think because it is looking at the default fragment menu "Maps";

https://www.neurosynth.org/analyses/terms/dorsomedial%20prefrontal/

What do I need to do to get round this and scrape the study data (name of study, authors, journal)?

Comment: Note that `rvest` cannot run JavaScript. Make sure you are looking at the data from the "Sources" tab, not the "Elements" tab when scraping data. Note that most modern websites use a lot of JavaScript to load data beyond what's in the HTML source. If you want to access a website that uses JavaScript you'll need to use a tool like RSelenium or you'll need to comb through the Network tab to see where it's pulling data from and hopefully that will be a format you can use.

Comment: Great. I used RSelenium and I now have the first 10 of the 178 papers loaded in so I'm making progress! The rest of the papers are stored in tabs accessed on the page by clicking Page 1, Page 2, .. etc  - any idea how I scrape those?

Comment: Use RSeleium to click the tabs. It should be able to anything you can do in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could call the API and pass in the analysis id present in the page source. This will return all 178 listings.

```
library(jsonlite)
library(purrr)
library(rvest)

link <- "https://www.neurosynth.org/api/analyses/724/studies?dt=1"
data <- jsonlite::read_json(link)$data

df <- map_dfr(data, ~ {
  node <- read_html(.x[[1]]) %>% html_node("a")
  data.frame(
    title = node %>% html_text2(),
    webpage = node %>% html_attr("href") %>% url_absolute(link),
    authors = .x[[2]],
    journal = .x[[3]],
    loading = .x[[4]]
  )
})
```

This swagger file is still working but doesn't list all routes:`https://neurosynth.org/api/swagger.json`

Don't know your ultimate goal with this but there are quite a lot of related GitHub packages and also the following python tutorial (not tested):
`https://nbviewer.org/github/neurosynth/neurosynth/blob/master/examples/neurosynth_demo.ipynb`

Comment: Wow. That's amazing. I wish I knew how it worked, but it's amazing! Can you recommend any tutorials?

Comment: Maybe this? https://www.dataquest.io/blog/r-api-tutorial/